# WAMP won't turn green. And the VCRUNTIME140.dll error

Tags: apache, wamp

WAMP won't turn green. It was working fine a couple of weeks ago. When looking at other answers on this topic, a lot said to install services in Apache.

When I do this, I get an error code stating:

> "The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem."

Comment: Look at this [WAMPServer forum TroubleShooting Tips POINT20](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) It gives you links to the microsoft C/C++ runtime libraries that are required to run Apache. You can try just installing the missing runtime and see if that fixes it. But you may have to uninstall 1. WAMPServer, 2. add the runtime, 3. Re-instal WAMPserver. **If so make sure you backup everything first**

Comment: In such situations I always ask myself who is doing such installation packages. Why not block the installation and only allow users to install when the packages are detected?! Or at least give it a separate dialog. This thread here has been seen more than 45k times (April 2016). A waste of valuable time...

Comment: This is not the exact answer, but MAMP exists for Windows and is not causing this issue... just saying !

Answer (score 151, accepted):

As Oriol said, you need the following redistributables before installing WAMP.

From the readme.txt

> BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure
>   that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise
>   Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation
>   will be faulty and you need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the
>   elements that were missing.
>
> Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9,
>   VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14 Even if you think you are up to date,
>   install each package as administrator and if message "Already
>   installed", validate Repair.

The following packages (VC9, VC10, VC11) are imperatively required to Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP versions VC11 and VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17

- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)
  The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
- VC13 Packages[/b] (Visual C++ 2013)
  The two files [VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/6/056DCDA9-D667-4E27-8001-8A0C6971D6B1/vcredist_x86.exe) and [VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/6/056dcda9-d667-4e27-8001-8a0c6971d6b1/vcredist_x64.exe)
- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015)
  The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685
- VC Packages x64 (Visual C++ 2017)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: @Amalgovinus Please remember that 64bit windows is designed to run 32bit and 64bit windows code. I have never heard of an issue where you cannot download and install these runtimes. Make sure you are getting them from the Microsoft site and not one of the `fix your dll sites` who know what has been done to the dlls you may get from there.

Comment: FWIW I downloaded and attempted to install each of the files. If my (64bit) system said it was already installed I just moved onto the next one. My wamp installation is now working.

Comment: Some of these links no longer work - see http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&prerequis=afficher for download links to all prerequisites

Comment: The single and only perfect solution by @sotoz

Answer (score 39):

Quite simply:

1. Uninstall wampserver
2. Install *[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)*
3. Install wampserver

Answer (score 9):

You need to install some Visual C++ packages BEFORE installing WAMP (if you have installed then you must uninstall and reinstall).

You need: VC9, VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14

In [readme.txt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/) of wampserver 3 (on SourceForge) you can find the links.

Be careful! If you use a 64-bit OS you need to install both versions of each package.

Comment: "Be carefull! If you use 64b OS you need to install both versions of each package."
I'm wondering how you pulled this off, because it seems impossible to me. the x86 installers won't allow you to do anything if the x64 version is installed.

Answer (score 9):

> VCRUNTIME140.dll error

This error means you don't have required Visual C++ packages installed in your computer.
If you have installed wampserver then firstly uninstall wampserver.

**Download the VC packages**

Download all these VC packages and install all of them. You should install both 64 bit and 32 bit version.

-- VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)--

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092

-- VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)--

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523

-- VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4)--
The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

-- VC13 Packages] (Visual C++ 2013)--
The two files VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

-- VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015)--
The two files vcredist_x86.exe and vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

**install packages with admin priviliges**

Right click->Run as Administrator

**install wampserver again**
After you installed both 64bits and 32 bits version of VC packages then install wampserver again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by installing :

- [Redistribuable Visual C++ pour Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679) (6.9 MB)
- [Redistributable Visual C++ pour Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49984) (14.1 MB)

*NB : 64 bit installation was enough, I had to uninstall / reinstall Wamp after that*

Answer (score 2):

Since you already had a running version of WAMP and it stopped working, you probably had VCRUNTIME140.dll already installed. In that case:

1. Open Programs and Features
2. Right-click on the respective Microsoft Visual C++ 20xx Redistributable installers and choose "Change"
3. Choose "Repair". Do this for both x86 and x64

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

After lots and lots of installing and uninstalling for a whole day and trying every packages for every answers in here, the only thing that worked for me was:

1. Uninstall Wamp and reboot
2. installing Visual Studio 2017 Community edition and choose "Web development" and check all of the options in the right site. Here's a screenshot:
   [image]

This somehow install something that is needed for Wamp as well.

3. install Wamp, and you should be all good.

Link to [visual studio 2017 Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 1):

### WAMP is not turning GREEN? Don`t panic

First of all check your windows update by searching "Windows Update"

**or**

Download updates from microsoft windows site (i had windows 7 x64 updated to service pack 1 full) [windows 7 Service pack 1 download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842)

Now there are some more downloads that support WAMP for installing time

> From the readme.txt
>
> BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure
> that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise
> Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation
> will be faulty and you need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the
> elements that were missing.
>
> Make sure you are "up to date" in the redistributable packages VC9,
> VC10, VC11, VC13 and VC14 Even if you think you are up to date,
> install each package as administrator and if message "Already
> installed", validate Repair.
>
> The following packages (VC9, VC10, VC11) are imperatively required to
> Wampserver 2.4, 2.5 and 3.0, even if you use only Apache and PHP
> versions VC11 and VC14 is required for PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17
>
> VC9 Packages (Visual C++ 2008 SP1)
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092
>
> VC10 Packages (Visual C++ 2010 SP1)
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13523
>
> VC11 Packages (Visual C++ 2012 Update 4) The two files
> VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and  VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on
> the same page:
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
>
> VC13 Packages[/b] (Visual C++ 2013) The two files
> VSU4\vcredist_x86.exe and VSU4\vcredist_x64.exe
>
> VC14 Packages (Visual C++ 2015) The two files vcredist_x86.exe and
> vcredist_x64.exe to be download are on the same page:
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685
>
> VC Packages x64 (Visual C++ 2017)
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads