# php installation using Wampserver

Tags: php

Wampserver:After the installation of wampserver is complete I am getting the belo error - VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing on your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
How to fix this?

Comment: Did you try and reinstall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wamp Won't Turn Green & VCRUNTIME140.dll error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215395/wamp-wont-turn-green-vcruntime140-dll-error)

Comment: You need to install needed Visual C++ packages before installing WAMP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811668/php7-missing-vcruntime140-dll

Comment: what is the PHP version ?