# wamp server using my sql and java swing as front end

Tags: java, mysql, sql, wamp

I run 64 bit wamp on 64 bit window 7 but give  error mscvr.DLL file missing 
 How I can fix it

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215395/wamp-wont-turn-green-vcruntime140-dll-error

Answer (score 0):

I think this post can help you.

[WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557245/wamp-shows-error-msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-install)

It's another DLL file, but the solution should be the same since both files are part of the `Microsoft Visual C++.`

Answer (score 0):

`MSVCR100.dll` is among one of the several dll files in your Windows OS. A simple solution is to install C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

This will fix your problem in no time. Install it after or before your WAMP installation and reboot your PC. Good Luck

Comment: installing C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 may even solve other similar unknown issues in your PC so i advise you should.